# Flutter SpannableGrid row package height issue

Tags: flutter

I used the package spannable_grid 0.3.0. [text](https://pub.dev/packages/spannable_grid/example)

My code is:

```
content = SpannableGrid(
          gridSize: SpannableGridSize.parentHeight,
          showGrid: true,
          columns: 3,
          rows: 1,
          cells: _getCells(),
        );

List<SpannableGridCellData> _getCells() {
    var result = <SpannableGridCellData>[];

    result.add(SpannableGridCellData(
      column: 2,
      row: 1,
      columnSpan: 2,
      id: "Test Cell 1",
      child: Text("test"),
    ));
    result.add(SpannableGridCellData(
        column: 1,
        row: 1,
        // columnSpan: 4,
        id: "Test Cell 2",
        child: Text("test")));
    return result;
  }
```

I didn't mention any height. But some height is applied. How to remove the height?

Need to remove the extra height from child. Please find my image.

[image]